# Can "File History" be backed up to an NFS-share?

Tags: windows, backup, windows-11, network-shares, nfs

My Windows 11 desktop mounts this particular filesystem using NFS -- it is *not* available as a Windows share -- as drive `N:`.

When I specify `N:\MyBackups` as the destination in the "File History" dialog, the path is automatically translated to `\\server\share\MyBackups`.

I then start getting occasional errors about the drive "disconnecting" -- and how my File History will be backed up locally until the drive returns.

I *suspect* this is due to this translation -- which omits the protocol. When the backup program tries to access the share, it is treating it as a Windows (SMB) share, rather than using NFS.

Is there some way I could force it to use the NFS-protocol -- such as by correcting the above translation back to `N:\MyBackups`?

Comment: I don't have one to test with, but take a look at `%localapppdata%\Microsoft\Windows\FileHistory\Configuration\Config.xml` and see if it contains some target path options? Even if you give it a better path, I think it's unlikely to work, because NFS mounts are session-specific in windows, just like network shares. Services like the "File History Service" run in a different session, so they can't see your mounts. You can get around this by mounting it as `SYSTEM`, but it's awkward to do - see the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34895821/7411885